# Output buffering in php with high hits

Tags: php, performance, buffer

I have a website with 200 000 visits in day, and using php output buffer, I have a questions:

With these number of hits, is the use of output buffering, right or not?

I use MVC Framework and i should using output buffer!

Comment: The most important thing in your case is to cache. Are your views cached?

Comment: Regarding output buffering a quick google search gave me [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556613/php-output-buffering-sounds-like-a-bad-idea-is-it), perhaps it might answer your question.

Comment: have 200000 visits  a day visitors website and you don't know the output buffering ?

Comment: i not using html cache, and i caching mysql data, such as memcache!

Comment: 200000 hits/day = ~2.3hits/second. that's a very very light load, unless you're serving off an 8088-4.77mhz, or ENIAC.

Comment: About which kind of output buffering are you talking? Please add the code you're using that is related to the buffering. If this is about the PHP output buffer, which configuration do you use? Also do you run into actual bottlenecks? If not, it seems that there is no problem. If yes, what is the bottleneck? I/O? CPU? Memory?

Comment: @MarcB: Never seen a site that get's the total visits equally distributed over the whole day. Never.

Comment: @hakra except for this one, ohhhhh burrrneedd! lol

Answer (score 1):

Output buffering never hurts, depending on what you're caching and if you want it to expire.  I would use Memcache or APC, cache your pages for a certain period of time.  Use a conventional Key system for proper identifiers on each page or resource and create triggers when something is updated to automatically reset the cache. (Use a PEAR Daemon for instance)

If it's a lot of database utilization, I would just cache data sets and let the pages serve up  naturally.  With APC, you're already freeing up a lot of I/O resources.